# как сделать ссылку на статью через категорию статьи. Django

Tags: python, django

У меня есть категории. Я добавляю их через админ сайт, затем добавляю статью и привязываю ее к какой-то категории. Я хочу сделать ссылку из моей категории статьи - на саму статью. Как это сделать?

я пробовал написать так: <a href="{% url 'blog:article' article.url_article %}"{{ article.title }}/a>
но эта запись выдает ошибку:
NoReverseMatch at /PythonWorld/kursy Reverse for 'article' with arguments '('online-learning',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['PythonWorld/(?P<category_article>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']

**мой urls.py уровня блога**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('<slug:category_article>', views.category_page, name='category_article'),
    path('<slug:category_article>/<slug:article>', views.current_article, name='article'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def category_page(request, category_article):
    current_category = CategoryArticle.objects.get(url_category_article=category_article)
    category_list = Article.objects.filter(category_article=category_article)
    return render(request, 'articles/articles/current_category.html',{'current_category': current_category, 'category_list': category_list})
```

**models.py 'обрезанный'**

```
class CategoryArticle(models.Model):
    url_category_article = models.SlugField(primary_key=True, default="")


class Article(models.Model):
    category_article = models.ForeignKey(CategoryArticle, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    url_article = models.SlugField(primary_key=True, default="")
```

**html категории**

```
{% for article in category_list %}
    <a href="{% url 'blog:article' article.url_article %}">{{ article.title }}</a>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В паттерне url `path('<slug:category_article>/<slug:article>'` он ждет два аргумента - категорию и статью.
В шаблоне в url вы передаете только статью `a href="{% url 'blog:article' article.url_article %}"`

Вам нужно добавить в шаблон дополнительный аргумент - url вашей категории
и соответственно ждать оба этих аргумента во view

Comment: спасибо вам большое!  <a href="{% url 'blog:article' current_category.url_category_article article.url_article %}">ссылка 1</a> помогло мне